# Plotly Choropleth Map Not Showing Up

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to display a Plotly Choropleth Map in Jupyter Notebooks (I'm a beginner with this type of stuff) and for some reason it won't display correctly.

The csv file I am using for it can be found here:

https://www.kaggle.com/ajaypalsinghlo/world-happiness-report-2021

Here is the code leading up to the choropleth:

```
# here we're assigning the hover data columns to use for our choropleth map below

hover_data_cols_df = ['Country', 'Life Ladder', 'Log GDP per capita', 'Social support', 'Healthy life expectancy at birth', 'Freedom to make life choices', 'Generosity', 'Perceptions of corruption']
df.groupby('Year').Country.count()
```

and here is the code for the actual choropleth:

```
choropleth_map = px.choropleth(df, 
                locations="Country",
                color='Life Ladder', 
                hover_name = 'Life Ladder',
                hover_data = hover_data_cols_df,
                color_continuous_scale = px.colors.sequential.Oranges,
                animation_frame="Year"
               ).update_layout (title_text = 'World Happiness Index - year wise data', title_x = 0.5,);
iplot(choropleth_map)
```

I'm not getting any error messages attached to it currently, however when I check my console log on my browser, I do find this error:

```
Wolrd-Happiness-Report.ipynb:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:17
at t.attachWidget (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at t.insertWidget (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at x._insertOutput (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at x.onModelChanged (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at m (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at Object.l [as emit] (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at e.emit (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at c._onListChanged (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
at m (jlab_core.64abc115a1efeec58694.js?v=64abc115a1efeec58694:2)
```

I'm not too sure if this is related or not!

Thanks all!

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use columns from the df that don't exist. The arguments you can use are: `Country name,Regional indicator,Ladder score,Standard error of ladder score,upperwhisker,lowerwhisker,Logged GDP per capita,Social support,Healthy life expectancy,Freedom to make life choices,Generosity,Perceptions of corruption,Ladder score in Dystopia,Explained by: Log GDP per capita,Explained by: Social support,Explained by: Healthy life expectancy,Explained by: Freedom to make life choices,Explained by: Generosity,Explained by: Perceptions of corruption,Dystopia + residual`

Answer (score 2):

Your task requires a setting that associates a country name with a country on the map. It requires that the location mode be the country name.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./data/world-happiness-report.csv', sep=',')
df.sort_values('year', ascending=True, inplace=True)
hover_data_cols_df = ['Country name', 'year', 'Life Ladder', 'Log GDP per capita', 'Social support', 'Healthy life expectancy at birth', 'Freedom to make life choices', 'Generosity', 'Perceptions of corruption']
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    locations="Country name",
                    locationmode='country names',
                    color='Life Ladder', 
                    hover_name = 'Life Ladder',
                    hover_data = hover_data_cols_df,
                    color_continuous_scale = px.colors.sequential.Oranges,
                    animation_frame="year"
               )
fig.update_layout (title_text = 'World Happiness Index - year wise data', title_x = 0.5,);

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: We need to sort the data by year to get the year order of the sliders correct. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much, I appreciate it!